# org-mode in-buffer todo setting not working as expected

Tags: org-mode, todo, buffer-local

I am using org-mode TODO tracking change (in-buffer settings) and I'm having some issues. All the info is taken from the official docs (https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-TODO-state-changes.html)

I have added the buffer setting line at the top:

```
#+TODO: TODO(t) BUG(b) WAIT(w@/!)| DONE(d@/!) CANCELLED(c@/!)
```

and it's working, except two features I would like to have:

1. When changing to the WAIT state, it won't ask me for a note and the timestamp is not recorded either.
2. The DONE state is not grayed out as it's the case with CANCELED, despite both being specified after the "|" pipeline character.

I have not tested the same setting in a global init.el config because I need this setting different for each file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time I posted my question I have manage to find the culprit. Posting it with an answer just in case others need to see this.

The setting line was missing a space after the WAIT state and the "|" pipeline, which caused both issues.

Correct syntax:

```
#+TODO: TODO(t) BUG(b) WAIT(w@/!) | DONE(d@/!) CANCELLED(c@/!)
```